# Can SQL Server 2008 R2 be used to allocate resources by specific program?

Tags: sql, cpu-usage

Recently, I have come into a scenario where I have been brought in to help manage a hosted system where we host our own product for our customer.  Each customer is given a unique user to a specific SQL instance, and we are running multiple instances, however one instance may have between 50 and 100 users.  We also allow partnered third-party vendors to run software that, also, accesses the same client's database as our own software allows for the same user.  What I have run into, however, is that the third-party programs are often poorly implemented and will consume huge amounts of cpu bogging the customer down.  I know, using resource governer, you can limit the amount of resources a specific user has access to.  However, I am wondering if there is a way to limit the resources a specific program name has access to, or, set it at a lower priority?  We have a limited time frame for when these third-part applications can run, so I cannot stretch the timing of the application any further.  I have not found any way so far to limit resources or priority of a specific program as it accesses SQL, I was wondering if there were any resources for this sort of information that has not come up in my searches?

Comment: There probably aren't too many cases where you'd want to slow down the SQL portion of a system, so I doubt many solutions exist for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some reading and by the looks of it, using Resource Governor, you can classify each session/connection and assign it to a particular resource pool.  The resource pool is what can limit the resources as you see fit.  In order to accomplish this however, you would need to define a classifier function that would look at attributes of the session and make the determination of which resource pool the connection would belong to.

You could use the `APP_NAME()` function in SQL (within the classifier function) to fetch the application name that is making the connection.  And then assign to a resource pool with lessor resources assigned.

Reference Links:

Resource Governor - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866(v=sql.105).aspx

Create and Test a Classifier User-Defined Function - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645892(v=sql.105).aspx